# How to properly save and load a model Pipeline that contains a CountVectorizer step in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pickle, pipeline

I am relatively new to python. I come from R.

I am trying to save a pre-trained model in which I use Pipeline with CountVectorizer and other steps.

I've checked some questions refering to the `NotFittedError: Vocabulary not fitted or provided` when loading the pickle of a pre-trained model with Countvectorizer. Usually, people recommend to save the `vectorize` object (`vect` in my case) as a separate object. However, I haven't found anything related to how to do it when we have a model Pipeline.

So, I would appreciate any help you can provide on this matter; showing how to properly save the whole Pipeline as a single object so it can be loaded later; or how to save and load each part of the Pipeline separately.

Here is an example:

```
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
...
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline as Pipeline_imblearn
from imblearn.under_sampling import TomekLinks
...
import pickle

# load some data here

text_clf = Pipeline_imblearn([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer(binary=True, ngram_range = (1,2), stop_words=stoppers3)),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('undersampler', TomekLinks()),
    ('clf', svm.SVC(kernel='rbf')),
    ])

# svm - clf params
Cs = [10**(-1), 10**(0), 10**(1), 10**(2)]
gammas = [10**(-2), 10**(-1), 10**(0), 10**(1)]

param_grid = {'clf__C': Cs, 'clf__gamma': gammas}

gs_text_clf = GridSearchCV(text_clf, param_grid, cv=5)

gs_text_clf = gs_text_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# save object to a pickle
filename = 'SVM_model.mdl'
pickle.dump(gs_text_clf, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

After loading the pickle again, I got the aforementioned error when trying to make predictions for new data .